# Is there a way to use a method/function as an expression for .loc() in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've been going crazy trying to figure this out. I'm trying to avoid using df.iterrows() to iterate through the rows of a dataframe, as it's quite time consuming and .loc() is better from what I've seen.

I know this works:

```
df = df.loc[df.number == 3, :]
```

And that'll basically set df to be each row where the "number" column is equal to 3.

But, I get an error when I try something like this:

```
df = df.loc[someFunction(df.number), :]
```

What I want is to get every row where someFunction() returns True whenever the "number" value of said row is set as the parameter.

For some reason, it's passing the entire column (the dataframe's entire "number" column, in this example), instead of the value of a row as it iterates through the row, like the previous example.

Again, I know I can just use a for loop and .iterrows(), but I'm working with around 280,000 rows and it just takes longer than I'd like. Also have tried using a lambda function among other things.

Comment: its not clear to me what you are asking ... maybe you want `df.apply` which will pass each row ... but  that is probably not the best way to do what you are trying to do (Im not quite clear what you are trying to do or why you cant just do the indexing like you put in your first example)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've tried df.appy as well. Here's another example:

I have a table with a "numbers" column. I have a function that checks to see whether a number is between 0 and 10. Now, I want to get all rows in my dataframe where the number in "number" is between 0 and 10, so I use the function I wrote as so:

df = df.loc[myFunction(df.number), :]

However, instead of going row by row and passing one value, one by one, it is passing the entire "number" column of the dataframe into the "myFunction(df.number)" call, for some reason. This causes an issue. Does that help clarify it a bit?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I hope this helps clarify it a bit. The data I'm working with is more complicated than my example, that's why I have to use a function (working with IPs and IP ranges).

Comment: I suspect you are chasing the wrong thing ... there are lots of really great ways to select stuff in pandas... going row by row is not one of them

Comment: Sadly, I do think I need to go row by row, as after I have found the rows that I need, I then need to use the data from each row to calculate data for new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"number": [x for x in range(10)]})


def someFunction(row):
    if row > 5:
        return True
    else:
        return False


df = df.loc[df.number.apply(someFunction)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   number
6       6
7       7
8       8
9       9
```

Comment: This helped me do what I wanted it to do! Thanks, however, as someone else said, apply() seems to still take a long time. Still appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad it helps. There may be a better solution than apply but I think we'd probably need to see what your function actually does.

Comment: @osint_alex I dont see the difference between `df.loc[df.number.apply(...)]` and just directly doing `df.number.apply(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Apply is slow - if you can, try to just put the complex vectorization logic in the function by taking in series as arguments:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
df['b'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def my_func(series1, series2):
  return (series2 > 3) | (series1 == series2)

df.loc[my_func(df.b, df.a), 'new_column_name'] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous function with .loc
x refers to the dataframe you are indexing

```
df.loc[lambda x: x.number > 5, :]
```

Comment: The only answer (until mine) that pushes the for loop into C for speed, and makes sense in the context of the question. However, I can't see the use for the anonymous function in this case. If inlining it, then inline it to 'df.loc[df.number > 5, :]' which is more explicit, since one doesn't have to guess that a lambda inside a loc will know to use the dataframe as it's argument. If you want a separate function for interface reasons, then make it separate. Any reason for the lambda that goes over my head?

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

1. Create a new column using the pandas `apply()` method and a lambda function that returns either true or false depending on `someFunction()`. Then, use `loc` to filter on the new column you just created.
2. Use a for loop and `df.itertuples()` as it is way faster than `iterrows`. Make sure to look up the documentation as the syntax is slightly different for `itertuples`

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this will work

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['number'] = np.arange(10)
display(df[df['number']>5])
display(df[df['number']>2][df['number']<7])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Your idea with someFunction is good and will work. You seem a bit confused that it gets the whole column at once instead of one row at a time. This is not strange however. If you pass the whole column like you show, it will get the whole column. If you wanted elementwise, you'd have to iterate over the elements and send them one by one.

Since you want speed, the challenge is to make someFunction fast. For this, it's good that the whole column is sent at once. Iterating over that column in Python will be slower than some other approaches. I would start checking if someFucntion can be expressed using vectorised Pandas or Numpy operations that operate on the whole column. In this case, there is still a for loop somewhere, but it is pushed down into the underlying C code which is faster. (Python is implemented in C.) Vectorised Pandas and Numpy operations is the most common and often most convenient way to improve the speed for large data in Python. It's more or less the purpose of Numpy. Pandas is built for convenience and clean code when handling data, and uses Numpy to do the heavy lifting.

In the comments you bring up checking if the column values are between 0 and 10 as an example someFunction. In this case, it can be expressed

```
def someFunction(series):
    return((0 < series) & (series < 10))
```

Then

```
df.loc[someFunction(df.number), :]
```

gives what you are after.

You can inline this function/expression if you like. In that case it becomes

```
df.loc[(0 < df.number) & (df.number < 10), :]
```

with the same results.